# VB approach to this excel function

Tags: excel, vba

This is the function and it works without any problem

1. **Substitute** all the occurence of char 160 in a cell with a null "".
2. **Trim** any empty spaces.
3. **Concatenate** the arrived number with char 160 again in the front.

act is the name of the referenced worksheet.

CAN anyone give a VB equivalent of this?

```
Range("a1").Value = "=+CONCATENATE(char(160),trim(substitute(" & act & "!RC[3],char(160),"""")))"
```

I have a telephone index with numbers on similiar lines for a match.

Comment: assuming you have `"61 2345 6789 "` in your 4th column (which is 3 columns from your current column) then what is your expected result? e.g. `" 61 2345 6789"` or `" 61 23456789"` ? There's a function I wrote and it works exactly as your above formula. However I would like to know your exact expected results given the input sample.. :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use any of the following

**A**. *Directly inputting it as a formula*

In such a case you will replace `.Value` with `.Formula`

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=+CONCATENATE(char(160),trim(substitute(" & _
                      act & "!RC[3],char(160),"""")))"
```

**B**. *Use `Application.Evaluate` Which will let you use the same code that you have*

```
Range("A1").Value = Application.Evaluate("=CONCATENATE(char(160),trim(substitute(" & _
                    Sheets(act).Range("D1").Value & ",char(160),"""")))")
```

**C** *Use VBA functions*

*Concatenate* equivalent is `&`

*Trim* is `Trim`

*substitute* is `Replace`

*Char* is `Chr`

*RC[3]* is 3rd cell on the right which is `Range("D1")` in such a case

So the above can be written as

```
Range("A1").Value = Chr(160) & _
                    Trim(Replace(Sheets(act).Range("D1").Value, Chr(160), ""))
```

Comment: @ Siddharth, Option C was on the lines I was looking for? But does the mention of D1 allow relative referencing , since I intend coopying the "A1" values to A2 , A3 and so forth?            @bonCodigo , the second option  seems Ok

Comment: Yes you can. remember `Range("D1")` can also be written as `.Cells(1,4)` Not it will be easier for you to change the the row numbers in `.Cells(1,4)`

Comment: @ Siddharth , The solutions do not give relative referencing on copy. Both Range(D1).value and .cells(1,4) seem to work only absolutely on copy.

Comment: @nagan: Wow a blast from the past! :D I am sorry, I didn't understand your last comment

Comment: @ Siddharth , I intend to copy the formula in A1 to A2 A3 an d so forth. If I use the term Range(D1).value or .cells(1,4) , I do not get Range(D2).value or .cells(2,4) in the cell A2. I want relative referencing. The excel method in my first post does that.